# Sklearn Aggregating Multiple Fitted Models Into A Single Model? (binary classification)

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn, ensemble-modeling, binary

My problem context:

1. dataset too big to fit into memory.
2. binary classification [0,1]
3. 30 csv files in a directory with exactly 30,000 samples (rows)
4. each file contains 15,000 `0` class and 15,000 `1` class (no unbalance)
5. model is xgboost.XGBClassifier()

If I iterate through these 30 files, fit a model, and pickle the model to disk; is it possible to aggregate these 30 **fitted** models into a single model? I am aware of `sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier` but that is used for:

> [sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html)
>
> Soft Voting/Majority Rule classifier for **unfitted** estimators.

Comment: I am using `XGBClassifier()` for xgboost. It outperforms SGD by a significant margin and unfortunately doesn't have a `warm_start`-like feature because of the nature of decision trees. I was able to use xgboost `xgb_model` parameter as in `xgboost.train(parameters, dtrain, num_boost_round=250,  xgb_model='model.pkl')` but its performance differs from the sklearn wrapper despite me setting the equivalent hyperparameters.

Comment: I think we need more context. Is this the same problem, split into 30 pieces, or 30 separate problems?

Comment: Some sklearn models allow a `prefit` option; there's been some chat about adding that to ensembles like VotingClassifier (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/12297) and StackingClassifier (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/16748).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Despite the downvote, the question is clear, and a common one I'm sure most stumble across after doing machine learning work for some time.

The goal was to make a strong**er** predictive model from multiple trained models.

Quote from my question:

> is it possible to aggregate these 30 fitted models into a single
>   model?

Answer: yes but there's no good functionality that allows you to do this in sklearn.

Verbose answer:

Imagine you have 30 CSV files that contain 15,000 `0` class and 15,000 `1` class samples. In other words, an equally balanced number of binary responses (no class imbalance). I generated these files myself because 1) the size of the data I'm working with is too big to fit into memory (point #1 of my original question) and 2) contains 97% class `0` and 3% class `1` (large class imbalance). My goal is to see if it's even possible to distinguish between a `0` or a `1` if the class imbalance issue was removed from the equation. If there were distinguishing features found, I'd want to know what those features were.

To generate each batch, I grabbed 15,000 `1` responses, and randomly sampled from the 97% 15,000 more samples, joined into one dataset (30,000 samples total), then shuffled them at random.

[image: batch files]

I then went through each batch and trained an XGBClassifier() using optimal parameters found from GridSearchCV() for each. I then saved the model to disk (using Python's pickle capabilities).

At this point, you have 30 saved models.

`/models/` directory looks like this:

```
['model_0.pkl', 'model_1.pkl', 'model_10.pkl', 'model_11.pkl', 'model_12.pkl',
 'model_13.pkl', 'model_14.pkl', 'model_15.pkl', 'model_16.pkl', 'model_17.pkl',
 'model_18.pkl', 'model_19.pkl', 'model_2.pkl', 'model_20.pkl', 'model_21.pkl',
 'model_22.pkl', 'model_23.pkl', 'model_24.pkl', 'model_25.pkl', 'model_26.pkl',
 'model_27.pkl', 'model_28.pkl', 'model_29.pkl', 'model_3.pkl', 'model_4.pkl',
 'model_5.pkl', 'model_6.pkl', 'model_7.pkl', 'model_8.pkl', 'model_9.pkl']
```

Again, going back to the original question - is it possible to aggregate these into a single model? I wrote a pretty basic python function for this.

```
def xgb_predictions(X):
  ''' returns predictions from 30 saved models '''

  predictions = {}
  for pkl_file in os.listdir('./models/'):
    file_num = int(re.search(r'\d+', pkl_file).group())
    xgb = pickle.load(open(os.path.join('models', pkl_file), mode='rb'))
    y_pred = xgb.predict(X)
    predictions[file_num] = y_pred

  new_df = pd.DataFrame(predictions)
  new_df = new_df[sorted(new_df.columns)]

  return new_df
```

It iterates through each file in a directory of saved models and loads them one at a time casting its own "vote" so-to-speak. The end result is a new dataframe of **predictions**.

Since this new dataset is smaller (X.shape x 30), it will fit into memory. I iterate through each batch file calling `xgb_predictions(X)`, getting a dataframe of predictions, add the `y` column to the dataframe, and append it to a new file. I then read the full dataset of predictions and create a "level 2" model instance where `X` is the prediction data and `y` is still `y`.

So to recap, the concept is, for binary classification, create equally balanced class datasets, train a model on each, run through each dataset and let each trained model cast a prediction. This collection of predictions is, in a way, a transformed version of your original dataset. You build another model to try and predict `y` given the predictions dataset. Train it all in memory so you end up with a single model. Any time you want to predict, you take your dataset, transform it into predictions, then use your level 2 trained model to cast the final prediction.

This technique performed much better than any other single model did or even stacking with UNTRAINED prior models.

Comment: This should be selected as the answer.